# Function to uncombine sequences without using append

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function that splits a sequence of couples into a couple of sequences, here's the code:

```
let uncombine s = 
  let rec ayx s1 s2 sr = 
    match s () with 
    | Nil -> s1, s2
    | Cons(((e1, e2), sr) ->  aux  (append s1 (singleton e1)) (append s2 (s(singleton e2)) sr 
  in aux nil nil
```

I want to do it without using `append` (not a recursive terminal function) because of the complexity.

Comment: The code you have written does not do what you claim it does. It is not clear whether you want a recursive terminal solution or not, and whether keeping the order matters.

Comment: i tested it and it does exactly what i claim yes the order is important

Comment: you define a function `ayx` that is never used but use a function named `aux`. This function uses the function `s` taken as parameter, it takes a unit during its first used and then what I presume is a list during the second use. The parenthesis are not matched.

Comment: also the function `ayx` does not depend on its input `sr`

Comment: For a tail recursive function construct the lists backwards and reverse them in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is the following:

```
let uncombine s =
  let rec aux sr =
    match sr with
    | Nil -> Nil, Nil
    | Cons ((e1, e2), sr) ->
      let s1, s2 = aux sr in
      Cons (e1, s1), Cons (e2, s2)
  in
  aux (s ())
```

of course you could also write a tail-recursive function and reverse it at the end. You wouldn't have the best performance but you wouldn't take the risk of getting a stack overflow.

Comment: Or just use List.split. But I think tail recursion was the goal, at least that's what I'm getting from "not a recursive terminal function".

Comment: "recursive terminal" is a direct translation from the french name for "tail recursion". Since there is a "not" in the parenthesis, I suspect that OP didn't want such a solution. `List.split` would work on lists but this is not the type we are working with here, or am I missing something?

Comment: `type 'a t = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a t` is how lists are introduced at school. It's just a list without the syntactic sugar. Which now makes me think this is a homework question.

Comment: I agree OP has been consistently posting their homework as questions. I also agree that it is an implementation of a list.  But I don't understand how you would use `List.split` since it expects a `list` as input, rather that the custom type used here.

Comment: I wouldn't use the custom type because a list already implements that exact type and has all the useful support methods already.